# extract information from a file with loop

Tags: text-processing, extract

I need help :) 
I have a file like this:

```
AA BC FG

RF TT GH

DD FF HH
```

(a few number of rows and three columns) and I want to put the letters of each column in a variable step by step in order to give them as input in another script.
So I would like to obtain:

for the 1° loop:

```
var1 = AA
var2 = BC
var3 = FG
```

for the 2° loop:

```
var1 = RF
var2 = TT
var3 = GH
```

for the 3° loop:

```
var1 = DD
var2 = FF
var3 = HH
```

Comment: You should post generic programming questions in StackOverflow.

Comment: ops, I am sorry :(

Comment: Hmm I think this is possibly on topic, seems loosely like a text processing question @PatrickNegus

Comment: @Zanna while that may be true, I don't know what language OP want to use; even more, its easier if collective programming questions/answers are posted in their correct sub-Exchange as it makes it easier for other people with similar issues to get answers.

Comment: `while read -r var1 var2 var3; do <something with them>; done < file`

Comment: @steeldriver that sounds like an answer?

Answer (score 3):

If you file has exactly 3 whitespace-separated items on each line (no blank lines for example) then you should be able to use a simple `while ... read` loop:

```
while read -r var1 var2 var3; do
  ./otherscript "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
done < "file"
```

If there are blank lines, then you should probably read complete lines and only parse the non-empty ones e.g.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ -n "$line" ]]; then 
    read -r var1 var2 var3 <<< "$line"
    ./otherscript "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
  fi
done < "file"
```

Comment: `read -r var1 ...` on a blank line would leave `$var1` empty which might be a more elegant way to test for blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your input file only provides arguments to script, the `xargs` is a reasonable choice in this situation. Lets take this script as example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is a test"
echo "var1 is $1 " "var 2 is $2 " "var 3 is $3"
```

We can use `xargs` with `-L1` for taking 1 line in file as arguments, and `--arg-file` to specify the file containing those arguments. Thus:

```
$ xargs -L 1 -r --arg-file=input.txt ./somescript.sh 
This is a test
var1 is AA  var 2 is BC  var 3 is FG
This is a test
var1 is RF  var 2 is TT  var 3 is GH
This is a test
var1 is DD  var 2 is FF  var 3 is HH
```

Notice the `-r` option, which prevents `xargs` from running the script on blank lines, which are contained in your input file example.